# Only show field type content added by user

Tags: views, 7, nodes

On my website I allow companies to add jobs, I allow a user to create one or more companies. When the user goes to add a job I have a drop down which lists all of the companies on the site, I want this drop down to only list the companies added by the user so they can choose which company they want to attach to the job. I can't find a way to do this via the manage fields screen. Below is a screenshot of my manage fields screen. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean you want if  user1 added 3 company and user2 add 4 company , user1 only see his/her 3 company in select list items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use views entity reference [this link](http://speaksdrupal.com/blog/custom-entityreference-handlers-using-views) is good tutorial about it .

So first create a views that show the current user company items ( the companies that the author (creator) of them is current user)  then add "Entity reference" display to it , then in your field settings in "Entity Selection" instead simple mode use "Views :Filter by entity reference" Then select your created views entity reference then enjoy it ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need to filter content created by current user. To do so you need to create a [View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) of what you want. Then in *Relationships* add

```
Content: Author
```

and in *Filter Criteria* add `User: Current` I mean this :

[image]

By doing this contents available in Views are filtered by the ones that current user has created them.